# Push Notification Update To Existing App: Will Users Be asked to allow or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I have an existing application which does not have a push notification feature. Now I have to update the application with push notification feature. My questions are

1. Will users be asked after updating the app to enable or don't allow push notification?
   If not, what will be the default?
2. Will the app be included in the notifications section of the settings?
3. How can I provide users to control enabling/disabling of the push notifications multiple times from the app?

I am sorry if any of the above questions are already answered, I have tried searching but have come across with confusing and contrasting solutions.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It works much like the location services (if you have experience with that). Since it is a new new feature, users will be asked to allow push notifications for your app when it first launched after the update.

If it has been set up properly, there will be an entry in the notfication settings. Users will have the ability remove it or add it as needed.

I am not sure by what you mean by:

> 3) How can I provide users to control enabling/disabling of the Push
>   Notifications multiple times from the App?

There are ways to customize what notifications users get, if the your web service is set up to store that kind of information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, The 3rd question I meant is is there a way where users can enable/disable Push Notifications from the App and not the settings.

Comment: @user2103707 Your user's will get a single 'do you want to allow push notifications' alert from your app.  As far as I'm aware they must make any changes to their selection through settings.  This is a security issue, as any code you might create to change that value could be arbitrarily called by any programmer.

Comment: Thank you, Well I read in many posts that On Update the permissions are not asked to user, or that they are also not included in the Notification Settings, So was very confused. I guess I am quite clear now, I have to re create provision profile, resign it..etc and then update the app, so that it asks user on first launch.

Comment: But then again I am still not clear about any ways to allow users change their previous answer( allow or don't allow notifications) from the app and not settings.

Comment: @user2103707 Yes you will have to re-provision your app to use push notifications. I try to keep searching to aswer your third question.

Comment: @RonLugge You are right about the securtity issue. The settings is one off deal, allow or disallow push notifications from the app, and banner notification or pop-up. In app, there are certain things you can do. Ex., I have and app where I can choose what ski hills I can get notified about snowfall. That kind of cusomization is done in app, with the proper web service to keep track of that data. It still requires the app to be added to the notification center.